# What is the best way to redefine the indentation rules of a major mode

Tags: indentation, advice

I am using js-mode in emacs 25.1. There are some indentation rules that are not editable through the provided customization variables. The specific one I have issue with is the indentation of arrow functions, they are not indented like regular anonymous functions. After looking at the function js--proper-indentation, the only way to edit it is to redefine the function. Should I redefine it in my js-mode-hook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably want to use `defadvice` to provide a wrapper around `js--proper-indentation`, rather than cometely redefining it. This will allow you to handle the indentation for arrow functions yourself, while calling through to the original function to handle everything else.

Comment: Better use `advice-add` instead of `defadvice`. This allows to used functions defined like normal functions (`defun`) for advices, change them while applied as advices and to remove them.

Comment: I used `advice-add`. Though I did end up using the `:override` for the WHERE argument and rewrote the `js--proper-indentation` function. Originally I tried use `:before-until`, but there where so many conditions to handle before I could event try to check for the arrow functions, it was easiest to use the real function as a template and make my adjustments.